# Standalone HornetQ and JBoss don't work together

Tags: jms, jndi, jboss5.x, hornetq

Using JBoss 5.1.0GA and HornetQ 2.1.2 stand-alone.The problem is this : While I can publish messages using a JMS client to the hornetQ server I can not publish messages using myApp that is deployed in JBoss.It says javax.naming.NameNotFoundException. I think it is because under GlobalJNDI namespace(viewed from jmx-console) there is no ConnectionFactory appearing.

How can I make the ConnectionFactory to be bound to the GlobalJNDI namespace so that JBoss will be aware of its existence?

Thx.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you're looking up the connection factory in your local JNDI.  You likely need to specify (or edit your JMS RA) a HornetQ Resource Adapter (RA) that allows you to connect to the "remote" standalone HornetQ server.